# rails form error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't figure out what the problem is.  When I go to the page with the form on it, i get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Here is my form code:

```
<%= form_tag ({controller: :skills, action: :update}, :method => :put, 
    :class => "skill-form", :remote => true) do  %>

    <%= select_tag :label,
       options_for_select( @crafts.collect {|craft| [craft.label, craft.label]}),
       include_blank: true,  :id => 'selectme', 
       :class => 'field field288 chosen-select' %>

    <%= submit_tag "ADD +", :id => "clickme", :class => 'button' %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this your full code that's generating the error?

Comment: Yes, if I take out this code, the page loads fine.

Comment: Lose the space between `form_tag` and opening paren `(`, that might be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove space from your `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: :skills, action: :update}, :method => :put, 
    :class => "skill-form", :remote => true) do  %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought Ruby ignores white space?

Comment: @Philip7899: this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19403603/2291093