# unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on rails, and I am trying to create a website that has groups, Groups have posts and posts have comments, whenever I try to run my code it shows the following error:

syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input 
pointing to this part of code in the comments view :

```
    <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= render'comments/form' %>
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

Groups show view:

```
    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= @group.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Description:</strong>
      <%= @group.description %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Interest:</strong>
      <%= @group.interest %>
    </p>


    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
      <% @post = post %>
      <% if @post != nil %>
        <%= render 'posts/post',  :collection => @group.posts%>
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>

    <h2>Add a Post</h2>
    <%= render 'posts/new' %>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(@group) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', groups_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', edit_group_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

_post.html.erb:

```
    <p>
      <strong>Title:</strong>
      <%= @post.title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Text:</strong>
      <%= @post.text %>
    </p>

     <h2>Comments:</h2>
     <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <% @comment = comment %>
        <% if @comment != nil %>
            <%= render 'comments/comment',  :collection => @post.comments%>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

    <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>


    <%= link_to 'Show', comment %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_post_path(p@ost) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', edit_group_post_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

posts: _form.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Add a post:</h2>
<%= form_for([@group, @group.posts.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

_comment.html.erb:

```
      <p>
        <strong>Commenter:</strong>
        <%= @comment.commenter %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <strong>Comment:</strong>
        <%= @comment.comment %>
      </p>


    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_post_comment_path(@comment) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', edit_group_post_comment_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

comments: _form.html.erb:

```
     <%= form_for([@group,@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :comment %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :comment %>
        </p>
        <p>
           <%= f.submit %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails form error: syntax error, unexpected keyword\_ensure, expecting end-of-input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067812/rails-form-error-syntax-error-unexpected-keyword-ensure-expecting-end-of-inpu)

Comment: I don't think this the same error. I have tried to adjust the spaces but nothing changed.

Comment: Too late, but there is a non-required <% end %> in Comments: _form.html.erb.

Answer (score 4):

You're not closing the first `form_for` block in `posts/_form.html.erb`.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>   <---- you're missing this tag
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I've added this, but still the same error.

Comment: @user3166918 well, there's another unclosed blocked `comments/_form.html.erb`. Just look for these kind of things in the rest of your code. It might help to see what line the error pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `render'comments/form'` with `render('comments/form')`. Or try adding a space between the function name and the parameter like this: `render 'comments/form'`.

Comment: thank ou so much for your reply. I've actually tried this but still shows the same error :(

Comment: It would help to see a line number. Make sure you have updated your code to match what @alfonso as well as what I posted in my answer. If doing those things don't fix your error I have a feeling it is caused by something outside the code blocks you posted.

Comment: You should try debugging your code by remove all the code blocks you have present here if no error occurs you know it is caused by one of the lines of code present here. Then start adding the code back in, one block at a time. This should allow you to determine exactly what line is actually causing the error. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
posts: _form.html.erb:
```

In this partial you have used two forms but closed only one form that is the second one. So you need to close the first form helper.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %>
       <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
         <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
       </div>
     <% end %>
     <% end %>       <!-- You are missing this end in posts: _form.html.erb and also you have another problem -->

comments: _form.html.erb:
```

In this partial you have closed form twice, so just remove one <% end %>

```
     <%= form_for([@group,@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :comment %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :comment %>
        </p>
        <p>
           <%= f.submit %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <!-- remove last "end" as it is an extra closing
```